# How to validate if a bean instance has been wired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a small framework that provides some `abstract` base classes that have to be implemented when using the library.

How can I create a validation routine that checks if indeed all classes have been implemented?

I thought I could maybe use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` of spring-boot, but that does nothing so far. Anyhow, my goal would be:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppCfg {
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BaseCarService.class) //stupid exmaple
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("MISSING BEAN!!");
    }
}

//must be implemented
public abstract BaseCarService {

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is not being triggered at all when the bean doesn't exist?

Comment: No not at all, no output.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` has the meaning of "use this bean (or configuration) if bean X is missing". So it's only useful in combination with components or configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this calling `ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(BaseCarService.class)` when your context has been initialized (for example from bean that implements `ContextLoaderListener`), i.e. something like the following:

```
public class BeansValidator impelements ContextLoaderListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
         if (ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(BaseCarService.class).isEmpty()) {
               // print log, throw exception, etc 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I'm not inside a web app, but just a local comand line app? There won't be any `ContextLoaderListener`, nor `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Why? `ApplicationContext` is the most basic thing in Spring. This is the factory that creates all beans and manages instances. This is THE Spring. So, it always exists.

Comment: Ok so I should go with @PostConstruct, or is there a class similar to `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: Not similar, just `ContextLoaderListener`. I think this solutiion is better than `@PostConstruct` because in this case you are guaranteed that the context is indeed created and ready. `@PostConstruct` just guarantees that the specific bean is created and all its dependencies are injected.

Comment: No, `ContextLoaderListener` is of `spring-web`, which I don't have included if an app is running only on comand line and is non-web application.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationListener could be used to get access to the Context after startup.

```
public class Loader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

       if (event.getApplicationContext().getBeansOfType(BaseCarService.class).isEmpty()) {
           // print log, throw exception, etc 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, but looks a little awkward if you are just going to throw an exception:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppCfg {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BaseCarService.class)
    @Bean
    public BaseCarService validate() {
       throw new NoSuchBeanDefinitionException("baseCarService"); //or do whatever else you want including registering a default bean
    }
}
```